# Subtract days from Current Date using Calendar Object

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am trying to subtract days from the current date using the java.util.Calendar object. My problem here is the days to subtract can be positive or negative. My code is as follows

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int pastValidationDays=2;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,  - pastValidationDays);
    }

}
```

As per the above code if the date is 20/1/2015 it will give me 18/1/2015

Now say if the pastValidationDays= -2(negative value) then also it should subtract from the current date. As per the above code if i say

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,  - pastValidationDays);
```

then it is adding up the days instead of subtracting. Say if the current date 20/1/2015 it is giving me 22/1/2015. But in this case as well i need the date as 18/1/2015.

One of the way i am doing is as below

```
if (pastValidationDays < 0){
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,  pastValidationDays);
}else{
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,  -pastValidationDays);
}
```

Is this a good approach or can it be done this way

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,  - Math.abs(pastValidationDays));
```

I want to subtract the days using calendar object only. I do not want to use JODA time and other objects. Please suggest other approaches if any. Thanks in advance

Comment: `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,  - Math.abs(pastValidationDays));` looks ok. You could use a temporary variable for clarity: `int numberOfDaysToSubtract = abs(pastValidationDays);`. But would it not make sense to get rid of that logic completely and only pass appropriate (positive) arguments to the method?

Comment: Yeah, just use abs..

Comment: Between the if and the abs, the abs is more brief > easier to understand > better. But as assylias said, it'd be best to restrict the "legal" parameters of that method to make its semantics easier. I mean, something like "this method returns a date before today in a number of days equal to the absolute value of the parameter" it's more complicated than "this method returns a date [parameter] days before today"